# PHP extensions not working from web directory while .html extension is

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a Codeigniter install with a directory 'sandbox' at root. In sandbox i have document 'poster.html'. If i change this document's extension to .php, I get a CI 404 error. If i leave it as .html it works!

**Edit:** I just confirmed that .php extension does not work from any of the excluded directories like: css/ or scripts/ .
Here is what the .htaccess file at the root directory looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|sandbox|css|scripts|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Current root directory structure:

```
application/
system/
css/
sandbox/
scripts/
.htaccess
index.php
```

Comment: where's the rule that produces the $1?

Comment: Check short / long tags in `php.ini`. Try changing your tags in the PHP file from **<?** to **<?php**.

Comment: Yes, the 404 is CI generated.

Comment: please post your directory structure, is the CI setup in root? `/` and then from root you have a folder called `/sandbox` ? If you can access a css/scripts file you should access a file in sandbox

Comment: Hi will be posting dir structure.

Comment: @DevlshOne: Hi even if change to long open tags, which I don't think I need to have since it's .php extension with html content only.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue is either you have a typo somewhere, or you have a ROUTE conflict.
I just recreated this with a new 2.1.4 CI install and created a sandbox folder with a php file in it.

I can confirm it is working 100%.  Double check your spelling.  You *shouldn't* be getting a CI 404 page for the `/sandbox/` folder based on your `.htaccess`

As an alternate debug approach, turn up your ci logging and check the `/application/logs` for detail on what is it throwing a 404 on.